# Seagate Expansion not loading up as a Disk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am in deep sh*t as my 1TB Seagate Expanstion Portable HDD (STBX1000301) stopped working all of the sudden. It was working fine, like crisp. I was copying data (in GBs) to it and suddenly it stopped working.

I got an error: `Error Drive not found` or something like that. Then I tried different ports and cable check (light turns on but doesn't blink).
It does detect as Seagate SCSI Device, but it neither populates sectors in Device Manager nor does Disk Management seems to have the 1TB Disk.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE ALREADY:**

1. Cracked open the encloser, and connected it directly to my laptop

   - Result: BIOS does not recognize the HDD
2. Connected via eSATA

   - Result: Not recognized

**WHY AM I TRYING TO GET IT ALIVE:**

It was my Backup Drive with ALL of my Company's Data, around 512 GBs of it. I don't trust the Service Centers here, they would rather charge 1000s of Rupees and do nothing and say sorry data cant be extracted.

I need to recover the data. Please can anyone help me?

**PS**: Device is still under warranty.

Comment: "Cracked open the encloser, and connected it directly to my laptop" --> "PS: Device is still under warranty.". This seems to conflict. Are you sure your warranty did not expire when you cracked it open?

Comment: I did it cleanly. I hope it didn't. Didn't say anything about it on the warranty card. Poor choice of words I think...

Comment: Normally speaking, if you use it differently than intended, you void your warranty. I'm pretty sure opening it will void it. If you happen to send it back, make sure to restore it in the state it was before opening it, as clean as possible and hope they won't notice.

Comment: I want to extract the data from it. That's the main reason I opened it in first place.

Comment: The warranty might get you a new drive, but it won't do anything for the data unless you purchased an additional warranty that includes data recovery. Does the drive spin up? Does it make any sounds? (By the way, external hard drives are among the least reliable storage devices in existence. Anyone who has important data only on a device of that type is asking for trouble.)

Comment: I wish someone could have told me that earlier. It doesn't include data recovery warranty. Yes It does spin up. No it makes no noise like the clutter is being it or something like that.

Comment: BTW, can a 5V only rated drive connect to the the main power supply providing both 12 & 5 Volts?